# button 'quote' & display into tinymce textarea

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I just created a 'quote' button, when we press it, i want it take a text and put it in a textarea.

It works with a basic textarea but I still have a problem,

I use the editor 'Tinymce' .., & I can't put the text in this one .

```
$(function() {
     
    var $answer = $('#answer');
    var $answerTa = $answer.find('textarea');
   
    $('.quote').click(function(e) {
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var postContent = parent.find('p').text();
        var quote = '[QUOTE]';
        quote += postContent+'[/QUOTE]';
        var answerTaContent = $answerTa.val();
        $answerTa.val(answerTaContent+quote);
         
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0},"slow");
         
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When TinyMCE appears on a page the original `textarea` is replaced by a series of `div`s and an `iframe`.  Once TinyMCE appears you cannot use jQuery to interact with the editor - you should use its own APIs.  There is an API to insert content at the location of the cursor:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#insertcontent

...or to replace the editor's contents entirely:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#setcontent

Comment: Okay thanks buddy, i just added this line ;         ' tinymce.activeEditor.setContent (answerTaContent+quote); '   and it works now ! :)